# Scheme standard functions?

Tags: scheme

Where can I find a list of the scheme [standard functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29#Standard_procedures) and descriptions for how to use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [PLT documentation](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/search/), which includes indexes into both R5RS and R6RS.  To restrict a search to R5RS, use `M:r5rs` as a search term, and to do it for R6RS use `M:rnrs`.

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/r5rs_8.html

Answer (score 0):

They're a bit dense, but you can always check the revised reports for whatever version of Scheme you're working with. So [this](http://www.r6rs.org/) will bring you to the 6th Revised Report on Scheme (r6rs). The report's 'Base Library' chapter will tell you which functions are available in Scheme's basic library, as well as provide examples of how to use them. You'll also find a document with information on the functions contained in Scheme's various standard libraries, which you can import and use in your programs.